# Webservice caching reverse proxy?

Tags: web-services, soap, caching, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'd like to put some kind of caching reverse proxy in front of a SOAP webservice
over HTTP to improve both performance and availability. 
Is there some software that
performs this? (Preferably free and easy to install/use).

The idea is here: the responses of the webservice vary with the request, but
for each request the responses rarely change. So the proxy could
store the responses for each request for some time, and give the cached
response when the same request is sent again. There is only a limited number
of different requests.
The proxy does not need to parse and understand the request or response. 
But it does need to understand HTTP POSTs and, say, construct a hash 
of the request in order to find the correct response. Caching by the URL,
as done normally in HTTP Proxies, does not help here.

(Of course one can cache the webservice's results in the application
that calls the webservice, but I am looking for a solution that is
standalone, independent from the application.)

Comment: What technology are you using? .NET can do this, at least with the old ASMX web services.

Comment: The technology platform?

Comment: As I said, I am looking for a solution independent from the application. That is, a standalone caching reverse proxy.

Comment: "Independent of the application" and "independent of the framework" are two different things. You might want something that works for all of your .NET applications, for instance.

Comment: What does the application's technology matter? I am looking for a standalone proxy that is able to cache SOAP webservices over HTTP. I don't care about the framework the proxy is written in, and the proxy should by definition work no matter what my application framework is: SOAP and HTTP are standards that should for .NET and Java and whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ventus Proxy For Webservices. it does exactly what you need.

http://www.ventusproxy.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works with SOAP or not, but check out [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/). It's a very powerful cache/reverse proxy.